# Form mapping that handles optional fields with custom validation

Tags: scala, playframework

My form looks like:

```
case class RegistrationForm(department: Option[String], name: String, email: String, employeeId: Option[Int])
```

Now what I need to do is, if the user entered the `department` input, then `employeeId` should be None.  And if they left the `department` empty, then `employeeId` will be a required field.

My mapping is currently this but it doesn't handle this logic:

```
val registrationForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "department" -> optional(String)
    "name" -> nonEmptyText,
    "email" -> nonEmptyText,
    "employeeId" -> optional(number)
  )(RegistrationForm.apply)(RegistrationForm.unapply)
)
```

Also, in my form, how do I create a hidden input field and bind it to my form property, because sometimes my url will be like:

```
/users/register?employeeId=293838
```

So I want to create:

```
<input type="hidden" name="employeeId" value="???" />
```

So this employeeId hidden input should be bound to the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `verifying` to build constraints between form fields *after* they've all successfully been bound to the case class.

```
val registrationForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "department" -> optional(String)
        "name" -> nonEmptyText,
        "email" -> nonEmptyText,
        "employeeId" -> optional(number)
     )(RegistrationForm.apply)(RegistrationForm.unapply)
    .verifying("Some error message..", reg => 
        (reg.department.isEmpty || reg.employeeId.isEmpty) && (reg.department.nonEmpty || reg.employeeId.nonEmpty)
    )
)
```

The first argument of `verifying` is an error message to use when the constraint is broken, and the second is a function of the case class you're binding to that returns `Boolean`. If the function returns `false`, the `Form` will contain a global error. I'm not 100% sure that's the logic you're going for in my example, as your wording is a bit strange (sounds like you're describing exclusive OR). You can also chain multiple `verifying` operations together if needed.

I'm not sure what your question about hidden fields is asking. A hidden field within the html form will be sent to the server with everything else, and bind just as any other field will.

Comment: Great thanks, sorry for confusing you but regardless your answer is what I am looking for.